# Error in webpack when compiling for Angular 4

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, asp.net-core, single-page-application

Hi being trying to go from working Angular 2 to Angular 4 for 3 days now. Last error I hope. Usual solution (

> /angular(\|/)core(\|/)@angular/

) doesn't solve it.

Error:

```
WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5877:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./~/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js
5893:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

I've tried these entries in webpack.config.vendor.js, one at a time, together and in different orders.

```
 new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('../src'),
            {}
        ),// FIx 3


new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580

new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
```

Comment: for me this `/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/` worked

Comment: Thanks. No its something else.